# Commands for getting and setting additional elements in a class and document

Tags: documentclass-writing

As I'm writing my first class, I'm wondering the best way to create additional elements that can be used both in the class file and the LaTeX document.

For instance, I want the user to set the `reportnum` in the LaTeX document using something like

```
\reportnum{QR-F100-EMCCP}
```

and then I want to extend the `\maketitle` command to include the report number on the title page and to use the report number in the headings of each page.

According to Peter Flynn in ["Rolling your own Document Class: Using LaTeX to keep away from the Dark Side"](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88flynn.pdf), I can use the following commands in the class file to create this additional element and extend the `\maketitle` command:

```
\def\@reportnum{\relax}
\newcommand{\reportnum}[1]{\gdef\@reportnum{#1}}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \huge\@author\par
    \Large\@title\par
    \if\@reportnum\relax\else\large\@reportnum\par\fi
    \normalsize\@date\par
  \end{titlepage}
}
```

However, I also want the user to be able to get the `reportnum` in the LaTeX document using a command such as `\thereportnum`. How should I modify the command, so that the user can both set and get the `reportnum` in the LaTeX document?

Comment: You can use `\newcommand{\reportnum}[1]{\gdef\thereportnum{#1}}`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel itym `\newcommand{\reportnum}[1]{\gdef\thereportnum{#1}\gdef\@reportnum{#1}}` (well, _something_ has to change from what you posted, else his `\maketitle` is going to fail.

Comment: The `\if\@reportnum\relax` test is wrong; try `\reportnum{AA-123}` and see. It should read `\let\@reportnum\relax` and then `\ifx\@reportnum\relax`, which is surely true if no change to `\@reportnum` has happened and false otherwise.

Comment: @wasteofspace: Why do you define `\thereportnum` equal to `\@reportnum`. This is redundant.

Comment: @egreg THe two above weren't online in a while, do you mind to answer?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the test is wrongly written, because with `\reportnum{AA-123}` it would return true.

For the main part, just define `\thereportnum` to print `??` (or an error, if you prefer, if `\@reportnum` is `\relax` or the value otherwise.

Better way:

```
\let\@reportnum\relax
\newcommand{\reportnum}[1]{\gdef\@reportnum{#1}}
\newcommand{\thereportnum}{%
  \ifx\@reportnum\relax ??\else\@reportnum\fi
}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    \huge\@author\par
    \Large\@title\par
    \ifx\@reportnum\relax\else\large\@reportnum\par\fi
    \normalsize\@date\par
  \end{titlepage}%
}
```